# Where can I find a definitive list of the ModelSim error codes?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I am running some VHDL through ModelSim. Each error and warning has its own error code (like this: `(vcom-1292) Slice range direction "downto" specified in slice with prefix of unknown direction.` This is just an example message; I understand what it means.

I assume that Mentor has a list of all possible error codes and a more elaborate description of what they mean, and how to avoid them. I did not find this error code in the PDFs that come with ModelSim, nor did I find it through Google. Any pointers anybody?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a modelsim command called `verror` with an `-all` option to list them all, and other options to inspect the messages further.

Comment: @Philippe: I was thinking primarily of Xilinx ISE/EDK, though I don't think this exists for the Altera tools either... happy to be corrected! In any case, even a definitive and comprehensive list of cryptic uninformative error messages isn't much help.

Comment: @Saar have you tried the verror command that Jan talks about? It _also_ gives a longer (4 lines) explanation for each of the short cryptic messages. Looks very useful

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in finding out information about a certain error then use the verror command in the Questasim GUI.
verror  
Better than going through the entire list. :)