# Where can I find a list of the ModelSim error codes?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, modelsim

I find this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749860/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-list-of-the-modelsim-error-codes). I can use

```
verror -all
```

in console. But I try to find documentation about all errors.

Comment: What error are you seeing that doesn't appear in the output of `verror -all` ?

Comment: I try find documentation, .pdf or smth else.It's necessary for me for more comfortably view

Comment: And also... If I want to view all errors - I print `verror -all` and can view errors since #9600 and not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the `verror` output to a file. Try this:

```
set ErrorFile [open "Errors.txt" w]
puts $ErrorFile [verror -all]
close $ErrorFile
```

Errors.txt will then contain the entire output of the command.